# Global try catch for extjs

Tags: extjs

Is it possible to surround the entire ext-js based code, as a global try - catch. Something like having the ext-application javascript file, so that not every function should be surrounded with a try-catch?

Comment: There is no point in surrounding entire ext-js code inside try/catch. Better follow MVC pattern with exception over request... which may help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[window.onerror](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/error2.shtml) is a handler catching all error events and sending them to the window.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, like this:

```
try {
  Ext.application({
    launch:function(){

    }
  });
} catch(err){
  alert(err.message);
}
```

What is wrong with the solution in your previous question?

You will still want to use try/catch in other areas though, when you need to handle exceptional situations.

Your other catch blocks should re-throw the exception after handling them.